# export mysql data to csv download file in localhost but not in server

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have used the code of download  mysql data to csv in php.It works fine in localhost.when i click on export button it download the file in localhost in csv format but when i run this code on server and when i click export button it print the data it did not download the file.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="export" value="export">
</form>
<?php 
require 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['export'])){
 $q= mysql_query("select firstname,lastname,email from  tab_Recruiter where status=1");

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Userinfo.csv');
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

$data = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$first = true;
 while($row = array_filter(mysql_fetch_assoc($q))){
 if ($first) {
        fputcsv($data, array_keys($row));
        $first = false;
    }
   // fputcsv($fp, $row);
fputcsv($data, $row);
}
exit(); 
}

 ?>
```

Comment: It might be problem in `mysql_query();` So see the error.
To see error add these line top of the page `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Please add your database connection to your post

Comment: I have used your code no error is shown in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances of errors:

- Your config may be different on the server.
- `<?php` and `header()` should be the first calls within the page.

Also, do not DOWNLOAD immediately with headers. For debugging purpose, disable your header() calls and see the output in the screen - if it contains errors.

Only if it works correctly, set the headers correctly to force a download.